# Transparent sprites in c++ with Allegro

Tags: c++, visual-c++, allegro

I'm learning to use Allegro. I'm trying to make my character cut out. How do I key out a certain color from my bitmap? which way is used for allegro?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might be places to start:

http://www.allegro.cc/manual/api/blitting-and-sprites/draw_trans_sprite

http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Alpha_channel#Drawing_to_the_alpha_channel_in_Allegro

Answer (score 0):

http://www.allegro.cc/manual/api/blitting-and-sprites/draw_sprite

"Transparent pixels are marked by a zero in 256-color modes or bright pink for truecolor data (maximum red and blue, zero green)."